# MySQL GeoSpatial function for ST_Distance_Spheroid? Metric used in return Type of GLength?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geo

> - Is there a ST_Distance_Sphere, ST_Distance_Spheroid equivalent function in MySQL's GeoSpatial Support?
> - If not, any way to emulate this?
>
>   ---
> - What is the metric used in return type of GLength (length of the LineString)?
> - The manual for [GLength](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_glength) says that *GLength() is a nonstandard name. It corresponds to the OpenGIS Length() function.* But I couldn't find any Docs for OpenGIS Length(). All I found was for [ST_Length](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html) are they the same?
>
>   ---
> - Also for accuracy do I need to specify the SRID(4326)? How Do I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySql 5.1 there are provided GIS functions **distance_sphere()** and **distance_spheroid()** functions. There is an [explanation](http://www.lenzg.net/archives/220-New-UDF-for-MySQL-5.1-provides-GIS-functions-distance_sphere-and-distance_spheroid.html) of the parametres and how to use them.

The length that is returned by *GLength()* function can be in either unit the coordinates have. So if the coordinates are in terms of degree there is no meaning of a length metric in degrees. To fix this problem the projections are used.

For WGS84 projection SRID = 4326 but for Spherical Mercator projection, SRID = 900913, which is compatible with the projection used by Google Maps. Spherical Mercator projection Mercator projection uses meters so the GLength function will return the length in terms of meters. [This](http://www.wrightopia.com/tag/mysql/) passage is helpful for projections in MySql.