# ST_Distance_Spheroid does not exist

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I've try use MySql function `ST_Distance_Spheroid` for calculating distance but got following error :

> ST_Distance_Spheroid does not exist.

Is something missing?

Comment: Hi Govind Samrow - can you show your code, and pinpoint exactly how and where it is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

ST_Distance_Spheroid is a function from the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL. With MySQL have a look here: [MySQL GeoSpatial function for ST_Distance_Spheroid? Metric used in return Type of GLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492294/mysql-geospatial-function-for-st-distance-spheroid-metric-used-in-return-type-o)